# how to replace Model schema Body parameter with actual example

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have spring-boot/spring-mvc and springfox swagger2 integration. I have attached sample screen shot. In parameter type of 'body' I have a Model schema which describe elements data types. string, 0 etc! How can I replace it with actual example so that I can 'Try it out' . That would be more useful for my API consumer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found the answer to this one, but I am going to answer this anyways.

The `@ApiModelProperty` has a property called `example`. You can make use of that.

`@ApiModelProperty(value="name of the user", required=true, example="John")`

[Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5NPX.png)