# How to summarize a object type in swagger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using springfox-swagger2 version 2.9.2 and springfox-swagger-ui version 2.9.2 to documentation a Spring Boot application through Swagger.

The problem is that a Object have many subclasses and make the example object stay very big, showing atributes that not will use in the context.

Someone has idea how can I only show the atributes that I need in the context?

[image]

Comment: [This link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) may be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a description and an example in Swagger with Swagger annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584658/how-can-i-set-a-description-and-an-example-in-swagger-with-swagger-annotations), [how to replace Model schema Body parameter with actual example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33133512/113116)

Comment: @Helen Can be duplicate, but none of topics has solution.